# How can I show line number where log uses?

Tags: javascript

I am using a simple log function. When I use log in my code, it shows the console message at the line number where it is written, not where it is calling (obviously it will). Is it possible that I get the line number where I am using it to debug my code properly? Thanks in advance!

```
/**
* Description: Console log
* @param {Object} p_sMessage
*/
function log(p_sMessage) {
    if(!Debug) { return; }
    else { if(window.console) { console.log(p_sMessage); }}
}
```

Comment: Try throwing an exception and catching it, then see what you can extract from the stacktrace.

Comment: @Florent Not a dup, this one is asking how to get the line number of the line **that calls the function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing your code to this:

```
log = Debug && window.console 
    ? window.console.log.bind(window.console) 
    : function() {};
```

This way `log` will simply act as an alias for `window.console.log` and therefor wont add another step to the stack trace.

Comment: Do note that `.bind` isn't supported in IE 8 or lower. If you do need to support it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

Comment: IE9 as well :( Though app is targeted to modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

use this function to get the line number of the caller:

```
function getLineNumber(){
    return (new Error).stack.split("\n")[4]
}
```

Comment: This gets the line number of the function, not the line number of the caller of the function.

Comment: no, this will get the line number of the caller, (new Error).stack.split("\n")[1] gets the line number of the function. You can try it to see it working.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited your answer to be a little more clear, and +1